# Stop a function if page has a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple function that appends the shipping details, to billing details in my woocommerce checkout. However I want this function to stop firing once a class has ben added to a div.

```
function billingclick() {
    $('#billing_first_name').val($('#shipping_first_name').val());
    $('#billing_last_name').val($('#shipping_last_name').val());    
};

$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing').on('click', function(e) {
    billingclick();
});
```

I can't use the one click function, as validation breaks this.

Is there a way I can stop the function if the div class is added?

e.g if .wpmc-step-shipping has the class current, stop the billingclick() function.

```
    if (!$(".wpmc-step-shipping").hasClass("current")) {
        // function here
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Put your if condition in the `billingclick()` function, and put the current logic inside thay condition. Then it will work

Comment: you have answered your question with last para

Comment: So how do I do this? Do I use the .stop() function?

Comment: But how do I do this? Do you have a coding example? So far I have this  function billingclick() {
  $('#billing_first_name').val($('#shipping_first_name').val());
  $('#billing_last_name').val($('#shipping_last_name').val()); 
  if (!$(".wpmc-step-shipping").hasClass("visited")) {
   $(this).stop();
  }
 };

Comment: You're overcomplicating this; forget `stop()`, it's not relevant to this at all. I added an answer for you to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to remove the click handler. While this is possible, you need to know exactly when the class is added to the relevant element, which is not always possible, nor simple.

A easier solution is to instead place your `if` condition within the `billingclick()` function and only update the `val()` of the required elements when the class is not present. Try this:

```js
function billingclick() {
  if (!$(".wpmc-step-shipping").hasClass("current")) {
    $('#billing_first_name').val($('#shipping_first_name').val());
    $('#billing_last_name').val($('#shipping_last_name').val());
  }
};

$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing').on('click', billingclick);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this :

```
function billingclick() {
  if (!$(".wpmc-step-shipping").hasClass("current")) {
    $('#billing_first_name').val($('#shipping_first_name').val());
    $('#billing_last_name').val($('#shipping_last_name').val());  
  }  
};

$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing').on('click', function(e) {
    billingclick();
});
```

Perform the `if condition` first inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers said, you can perform that check in your click handler:

```
//this should probably be renamed to be updateBillingWithShipping
function billingclick() {
    $('#billing_first_name').val($('#shipping_first_name').val());
    $('#billing_last_name').val($('#shipping_last_name').val());    
};

$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(".wpmc-step-shipping").hasClass("current")) {
        billingclick();
    }
});
```

You could also remove the event handler on `$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing')`

- `$('.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing').off('click')`
- see **[jQuery off() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/off/)**

You could also disable the '.wpmc-ripple.wpmc-billing' control.

- This is typically something you would describe on your component view since it is control state that reflects on state of another control (represented as a class).

Comment: I don't typically like enumerating multiple possible implementation approaches on a given question (I like to think higher quality answers on any given approach could emerge.), but I felt it was worth mentioning.